# Split a file in python - Faster way

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to be able to split a huge file (10GB) into multiple files. The only criteria is the header from the original file, have to be copied to all smaller files.

Thus, wrote a program in python to achieve the same. However, the program is painstakingly slow. Is there a way, to speed up the program.

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import os
import string
import glob

directoryToLoadFrom = "c:\\directory\\"
directoryToWriteTo  = "C:\\outputDirectory\\"
# Set the last business day
filesToRead = directoryToLoadFrom + "output*.csv"
listNoOfOutputFiles= sorted(glob.glob(filesToRead), key=os.path.getmtime)
# For each file name

splitLen = 100000

for filename in listNoOfOutputFiles:
    print ('Currently working on ')
    print (filename)
    entirePath, filenameWithExtension= os.path.split(filename)
    filenameOnly = filenameWithExtension.split(".")[0] #Just get the filename
    extensionOnly =filenameWithExtension.split(".")[-1]  # Just get the extension


    with open(filename, 'r') as curFileContents:
        header_line = curFileContents.readline()
        filecnt = 1
        while 1:
            curlineCnt = 0
            targetFileName = directoryToWriteTo + filenameOnly + "-" + str(filecnt) + "." + extensionOnly
            print ('Writing to ')
            print (targetFileName)
            outputFile = open(targetFileName,"w")
            outputFile.write(header_line)
            for line in curFileContents:
                outputFile.write(line)
                curlineCnt +=1 
                if ( curlineCnt > splitLen):
                    break
            filecnt += 1
            if ( curlineCnt < splitLen):
                outputFile.close()
                break
```

Comment: I´d guess that opening the file every iteration might have some impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize `multiprocessing` to complete this task quickly. Divide the logic in smaller chunks and then execute these chunks in separate processes. For example, you can make a process for each new file you want to create. Read more about multiprocessing [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)